# angular app not browsing when run with docker

Tags: angular, docker

I have used following docker file.

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/raju/ang-sample

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Above code used in docker file.  I have run the following commands:

```
1.docker build .

2.docker run -p 4200:4001 -it  ae16d2e80bc6
```

After the above commands and I have got the following output:

[image: output]

I ran the url http://localhost:4200/ in the browser. I don't get any response from the browser. Please Can any one help me?

As per suggestion , I have tried two ways:

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 -it  ae16d2e80bc6

docker run -p 4200 -it  ae16d2e80bc6
```

But I don't get any response from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the container, angular is listening on port 4200. But you are forwarding port 4001 from the container. Try using `-p 4200:4200` (or simply `-p 4200`).

Comment: As per you suggestion, I have tried  two ways. I don't any response from browser

Comment: Please check the ports with: "netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN". If everything works fine, you should see the requested port (4200) there. Try to determine, if the web server starts and works correctly inside the container.

Comment: I have ran command netstat -a  and getting following details >>>> TCP    0.0.0.0:4200           DPQRMWEB-GBD4I3083:0       LISTENING                                                                 etc..

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it seems application bind with localhost.

- Edit `packege.json` and update following accordingly

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
}
```

- Rebuild Docker image and then run the container, this time should work and the log will look like

```
Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:PORT, open your browser on http://0.0.0.0:PORT/.
```